# First and Last Date of Current and Previous Quarter For a Given Date in Scala

Tags: scala, date, datetime

I'm writing a code for automatic execution once a month, which will take the date from the computer as the start and end date for execution of a while loop.

```
 val today = new DateTime().withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Kolkata"))
 var start =  today.toString(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))
 val end = today.toString(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))

 while(start<=end){
    Data(start,end)
 }

def Data (start: DateTime, end: DateTime) {

    val start_temp = start
    val end_temp = end
    var start_temp_1 = start_temp.minusMonths(1).withDayOfMonth(1);
    var start_date_monthly = start_temp_1.toString(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))
    println("Last Month Start Date: " + start_date_monthly)
    var end_temp_1 = end_temp.minusMonths(0).withDayOfMonth(1);
    var end_temp_2 = end_temp_1.minusDays(1)
    var end_date_monthly = end_temp_2.toString(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))
    println("Last Month End Date: " + end_date_monthly)
    
}
```

The date in the variable `today` needs to be converted to the first and last date of

1. Previous month from `today`
2. Current and previous quarter from `today`

I was able to do the first one as displayed in the `Data` function.

Suppose today gets the following date - `2022-01-27T14:25:26.374+05:30`
The above function returns

```
Last Month Start Date: 2021-12-01
Last Month End Date: 2021-12-31
```

How can I achieve this for the second one - first and last dates of current and previous quarter?

Ex - today gets the following date - `2022-01-27T14:25:26.374+05:30`
I need to return `2021-10-01` and `2021-12-31` for the previous quarter
And `2022-01-01` and `2022-03-31` for the current quarter.

Certain solutions suggest using Spark SQL & Dataframes but that isn't applicable in this situation.

Is there a direct way do this as done in the month case? Or is a *udf* the only option here?

Comment: Is this for each date row that you have for the record in the dataframe

Comment: No, there are no data frames. Basically the start and end dates of both month and quarter will be used as filters in a query of sorts which will be executed. Since the goal is automation, so the dates need to be converted with some kind of function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following may do it. This is probably a UDF if it has to be applied to every row in the DF

```
import java.time.temporal.IsoFields
import java.time.temporal.IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR
import java.time.{LocalDate, YearMonth}

def printQuarterBeginAndEnd(localDate: LocalDate): Unit = {
  val currentQuarter = localDate.get(QUARTER_OF_YEAR)
  val currentYear = localDate.getYear
  val currentMonth = localDate.getMonth
  val startOfQuarter = YearMonth.of(currentYear, (currentQuarter-1) * 3 + 1).`with`(QUARTER_OF_YEAR, currentQuarter).atDay(1)
  val endOfQuarter = YearMonth.of(currentYear, currentQuarter * 3).`with`(QUARTER_OF_YEAR, currentQuarter).atEndOfMonth()
  println(s"Start $startOfQuarter ends $endOfQuarter")
}

printQuarterBeginAndEnd(LocalDate.now())
printQuarterBeginAndEnd(LocalDate.now().minus(1, IsoFields.QUARTER_YEARS))
```

Prints the following

```
import java.time.temporal.IsoFields
import java.time.temporal.IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR
import java.time.{LocalDate, YearMonth}

printQuarterBeginAndEnd: (localDate: java.time.LocalDate)Unit



Start 2022-01-01 ends 2022-03-31
Start 2021-10-01 ends 2021-12-31

scala> printQuarterBeginAndEnd(LocalDate.now().minus(1, IsoFields.QUARTER_YEARS)) Start 2021-10-01 ends 2021-12-31

scala> printQuarterBeginAndEnd(LocalDate.now()) Start 2022-01-01 ends 2022-03-31

scala> printQuarterBeginAndEnd(LocalDate.parse("2021-01-01")) Start 2021-01-01 ends 2021-03-31
```

Comment: There seems to be some issue with the logic. Today is 1st Feb, it is returning wrong start dates for the beginning of the current and prev quarter.

Comment: @PixieDev overlooked something , made a quick fix and a test on the CLI. Worth a look if this works

Comment: Yup, is working now. Thanks!